# Font is rendered differently in browsers on Ubuntu and Win 7. Ubuntu displays the fonts larger

Tags: 14.04, firefox, fonts, web-development, web-design

Faced with the problem of font rendering in browsers in Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu displays the fonts larger. 
Font Arial, size 16px appears as if he was in 17px in windows 7.

Page in firefox Windows 7 (font 16px):
[image: win7font]

Page in firefox Ubuntu (font 16px): 
[image: ubuntu font firefox]

Because the font is displayed larger, breaks down menu. The last menu item, moved under the first. If put 15px, then everything is displayed normally, as it should. The problem is present in chrome and firefox.

Microsoft fonts installed. No extensions are not installed in browsers (only Firebug in ff). 100% scale. Recently installed OS, no config files have not been edited. Screen resolution is the same. The problem occurs in firefox and chrome.

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you sure Ubuntu shows it 1px bigger instead Windows shows it 1px smaller? Have you tried Mac or another (completely different) GNU/Linux distribution such as Fedora or Slackware?

Comment: @CijcoSistems, i changed the value from 16px to 15px. Mac works fine.
Maybe same problem - [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1528043)

Answer (score 0):

Use an approach that doesn't rely on how the browser renders the fonts. Perhaps `<div>` elements with fixed `width` property.